# javascript auto fill text inputs based on drop down selection

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays

I'm having trouble with this... Hoping to auto fill the text input boxes in my form upon selection of the username from the dropdown. Users array comes from a mysql db. Not sure I have the javascript written correctly. First is my array which will just get called from db as $users. Thanks for looking.

```
<?php 
    $users=array
    (
        "User" => array 
        (
            "0" => array
                            (
                            "id" => "6",
                            "username" => "bsmith",
                            "full_name" => "Buddy Smith"
                            ),
            "1" => array
                            (
                            "id" => "2",
                            "username" => "lsmith",
                            "full_name" => "Libbie Smith"
                            ),
            "2" => array
                            (
                            "id" => "4",
                            "username" => "asmith",
                            "full_name" => "Andy Smith"
                            ) 
        )
    )
?>
```

then the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ids = new Array();
var use = new Array();
var ful = new Array();
    <?php
        foreach($users as $key=>$value) {
            echo "ids[" . $key . "] = '" . $value['User']['id'] . "';\n";
            echo "use[" . $key . "] = '" . $value['User']['username'] . "';\n";
            echo "ful[" . $key . "] = '" . $value['User']['full_name'] . "';\n";
        }
        ?>

        function Choice() {
            x = document.getElementById("users");
            x.value = y.options[y.selectedIndex].text;
            document.getElementById("ids") = ids[y.selectedIndex];
            document.getElementById("use") = use[y.selectedIndex];
            document.getElementById("ful") = ful[y.selectedIndex];
           }

        }
</script>
```

then my html:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<select name="users" onChange='Choice();'><option> </option>
<?php
foreach ($users as $key=>$value) {
echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value['User']['username'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<p><input type="text" id="ids" name="id" ></p>
<p><input type="text" id="ful" name="full_name" ></p>
</form>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("ids") = ids[y.selectedIndex];`??? wtf... I think you need more than an answer to this question, how about a [url](http://www.javascriptkit.com) where you can find some tutorials

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took some liberties, and don't really understand PHP so I made up those parts. Anyway, here's what I got:

http://jsfiddle.net/zunrk/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var ids = new Array();
var use = new Array();
var ful = new Array();

ids[0] = "";
use[0] = "";
ful[0] = "";

ids[1] = 6;
use[1] = "bsmith";
ful[1] = "Buddy Smith";

ids[2] = 2;
use[2] = "lsmith";
ful[2] = "Libbie Smith";

ids[3] = 4;
use[3] = "asmith";
ful[3] = "Andy Smith";


        function Choice() {
            //x = document.getElementById("users");
            y = document.getElementById("selectUsers");

              //x.value = y.options[y.selectedIndex].text;
              document.getElementById("ids").value = ids[y.selectedIndex];
              document.getElementById("use").value = use[y.selectedIndex];
              document.getElementById("ful").value = ful[y.selectedIndex];
         }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<select id="selectUsers" name="users" onChange='Choice();'><option> </option>
<option value="1">bsmith</option>
<option value="2">lsmith</option>
<option value="3">asmith</option>
</select>
<p>ids <input type="text" id="ids" name="id" ></p>
<p>use <input type="text" id="use" name="username" ></p>
<p>ful <input type="text" id="ful" name="full_name" ></p>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that sample is working well, thanks. However, I haven't had luck getting it to work on my site...next I need to troubleshoot my php. I'll let you know what I come up with.

Comment: got it working! Problem on my end was having a single quote in php array within javascript.
    '" . $value['User']['id'] . "'
solution was fixing that:
    \"" . $value['User']['id'] . "\"
as well as defining y properly and placing id in <select> as you provided. THANKS!

Comment: Hey dudess, you shouldn't use the Array() constructor in javascript, just use var a = [] notation. Its faster and new Array(2) doesn't do what you might expect. http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9780132902281/5dot-arrays-and-dictionaries/ch05lev1sec10_html

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to set the text of your input text fields.  You can do so by setting the "value" field.

```
    function Choice() {
        x = document.getElementById("users");
        x.value = y.options[y.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("ids").value = ids[y.selectedIndex];
        document.getElementById("use").value = use[y.selectedIndex];
        document.getElementById("ful").value = ful[y.selectedIndex];
    }
```

Comment: I tried that already. the y.selectedIndex is not grabbing that $key value. This is my array within the javascript.
    ids[0] = '6';
use[0] = 'bsmith';
ful[0] = 'Buddy Smith';
ids[1] = '2';
use[1] = 'lsmith';
ful[1] = 'Libbie Smith';
ids[2] = '4';
use[2] = 'asmith';
ful[2] = 'Andy Smith';

Comment: Please be more clear on your question next time.  Although I did notice that code was odd, you seemed to be asking how to set the value of the text field.
What are x and y in your javascript? You need to declare x and y.

Comment: set the value of the text input fields based on dropdown selection, "Hoping to auto fill the text input boxes in my form upon selection of the username from the dropdown"

Comment: Be clear with what exactly is wrong within what you are trying to do, next time. I understand now.  

Anyway, you missed the second half of my comment, "What are x and y in your javascript? You need to declare x and y."

Comment: sorry, I didn't see that ?. yes, x an y are not declared properly. How can I get $key into "y.selectedIndex"?

Comment: y.selectedIndex is meant to be the selected index of your dropdown, is it not?  For your dropdown's selected index, give your select tag an id, get the element by its id, and then get its selected value.  As for your arrays, are they being instantiated correctly?