# autopopulate fields with javascript and mysql query for dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I have a question on how to autopopulate a dropdown menu from column in mysql database, then autofill fields below based upon the user's selection. Please help! My code wont post correctly. I know how to query database and populate the dropdown but i cant get the fields to autofill below.

```
<?php
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
header("Location: dashboard.html")
?> 
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

else { 
mysql_select_db("Transgen", $con);?>
$query = "SELECT * FROM PartnerSetup" or die(mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            echo ($row['Partner']); echo "<br/>"; 
        } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you post what you already have done. This will provide developers the ability to properly assist you.

Comment: <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

else { 
mysql_select_db("Transgen", $con);?>
$query = "SELECT * FROM PartnerSetup" or die(mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            echo ($row['Partner']); echo "<br/>"; 
        } 
    ?>

Comment: "edit" your question with the code, using correct formatting. The above post is jumbled and hard to read.

Comment: above is juts the connect portion which i am able to do so correctly.

Comment: Even then. post your code within your question; using correct formatting. It'll be easier for developers to read your code. No one will have the efforts to look over the code and format it

Comment: i apologize i am new to developing. I understand the basics, but i would like to use a javascript to autofill the outcome of the selection from the drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time to get cracking;

First is your errors within the code;

> if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

This should be handled within your database connection information:

Example:

```
$host = "HOST";
$Username = "user"; 
$Password = "password"; 
$sql = mysql_connect("$host", "$Username", "$Password");
$conn = mysql_select_db("DATABASENAME", $sql); // Depending on what $sql and $con contain on your code.
```

Then your if statement:

> if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {...}

Should be replaced by:

```
if (!($sql))
{
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} // Kills the script if correct information could not be used to access the database
```

You have an echo

> echo "1 record added";

Which is outside your brackets `{ or }`

I am presuming this is inside either a `function` or a `$_POST/$_GET`
If so, then ignore the above

If not, then your script will be echoing out that string without need. This should be revised

You have also prematurely closed your PHP tags after: `mysql_select_db("Transgen", $con);?>`

^ In addition; You have !$sql and !con prior to $sql being set; on the line:

`$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");`

Which $con is stated after the initial variables, this might return an error if you not already have set $con and $sql prior to the first line displayed.

So your `$query` will not be executed, rather be shown in plain text to the user/person viewing the page.`

and in response to your question; if you are set on doing it through javascript, then look online.

This can be done through PHP by using a while loop with a few queries to populate your drop down menu within PHP it's self.

```
<select name="SELECTNAME"> 
    <?PHP
        $DropDownQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PartnerSetup");
        while ($Rows = mysql_fetch_array($DropDownQuery))
        {
            $Partner = $Rows['Partner'];
            echo "<option value=\"$Partner\">$Partner</option>";
        } // This will enable the user to submit a "partner" if needed in a <form> </form> setup
    ?>
    </select>
```

I would recommend appending errors within your code, **I'm going by what has been submitted, and what I can see. From what I can see, I have pointed out areas that might/will return an error.**

I would also look into the PDO functions; as MySQL is depreciated and will be removed from future PHP Revisions.

Comment: That worked to generate the dropdown menu. now i would like to auto fill two fields below based on the user's selection from the same table. database structure = VALUES(Partner_id, Partner, DestinationIP, DestinationPort)

Comment: Thanks again for your help i appreciate it. i was beginning to frustrate myself beyond recovery :)

Comment: @twatson0990 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525442/javascript-auto-fill-text-inputs-based-on-drop-down-selection

I would recommend reading this topic here; Glad to be of assistance and don't forget to +1 if this post helped you. Also, was I correct or incorrect with my other comments? Just for my own knowledge

Comment: you were spot on my friend. It wont let me 1+ because i am a new member. my apologies.

Comment: your suggestion looks like it is calling local variables instead of querying the database for possible results. IT is heading in the right direction. But, i would like the autofill fields to be auto populated from two columns selected. The reason i do not want them local is that this is going to be deployed in two seperate environments and i would rather make database changes than changes to page scripting.

Comment: The link I published a comment or two ago should do the tick, with a few tweaks on your end

Comment: would you mind assistance, or have I exhausted your efforts?? :)

Comment: At the moment. Im mobile and unable to code via mobile. If this can hang till later on Im sure we could arrange something.

Comment: can you PM me an email to reach you at if i cant figure this out... could be a long night. But, if all else fails i will regard your expertise. Thanks again.

Comment: @twatson0990 unsure how to pm. Admin@slayer-productions.com